# OSB 12c wlst scripting

Tags: weblogic12c, osb, wlst

Could you please help the procedure to follow for executing the WLST script on OSB 12c i.e from SOA suite/weblogic 12c server domain. As I see, I am not able to run a sample script to display the available proxies from the 12c OSB domain. I see the error as `ImportError:No Module named WLI` , I saw from the OTN forum few sb jars are to be added to the classpath to resolve this issue, I don't see those specific jars in the 12c domain, let me know where to see them (`sb-kernal-api,sb-kernal-impl,configwk-<version>`), but I have added them from the existing 11g OSB domain, it didn't help/work, further I see many `nullPointerExceptions` in the WebLogic 12c server console for referring the jars from the 11g domain. Please suggest with any example to change one of the customization entry in a OSB proxy/business service using the WLST in the WebLogic 12c.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You must edit $ORACLE_HOME/oracle_common/common/bin/wlst.sh

Change

```
export CLASSPATH
```

With

```
OSB_HOME="/Installation12c_Home/osb"

CLASSPATH=${OSB_HOME}/lib/modules/oracle.servicebus.configfwk.jar:${OSB_HOME}/lib/modules/oracle.servicebus.kernel-api.jar:${OSB_HOME}/lib/modules/oracle.servicebus.configfwk-wls.jar:${OSB_HOME}/lib/modules/oracle.servicebus.kernel-wls.jar:${CLASSPATH} 

export CLASSPATH
```

With this change you can user the OSB Management API.

Examples:

- https://redstack.wordpress.com/2011/08/25/getting-started-with-continuous-integration-for-osb/
- http://www.albinsblog.com/2013/08/customizing-osb-project-through-wlst.html

I hope that helps.

Comment: Thanks a lot Juan and Pang.  I am able to run the script in my local after editing the classpath as mentioned by you, I believe this information is not available any where in the documentations. If you have come across, could you please advice how it can be done to select the OWSM security policy to a proxy service using the wlst script, in 11g domain we have many proxy services referring to the wls policies now as per the Oracle recommendation in 12c, instead of Weblogic security policy want to select the policy from the OWSM store. Thanks a lot again.

Comment: Subash, if it worked for you please select it as right answer to resolve the issue.

Comment: Pavan, yes it is really helpful. I am indeed looking for a reply for other area in security policy selection in OSB proxy service using WLST.

Comment: Hi Juan,  I see now getting another error - import error: no module named security when importing this line                                                            from com.bea.wli.sb.security.management.configuration import ServiceSecurityConfigurationMBean                                                           I see security related jar in the %OSB_HOME%\lib folder so I have added it to classpath in the wlst.cmd file, but still getting this error, any idea how to resolve this please, as I have to modify the security policy in the proxy services to OWSM policy.

Comment: Hi Subash, try with from com.bea.wli.sb.management.configuration import ServiceSecurityConfigurationMBean. The jar is oracle.servicebus.resources.service.jar. I hope this helps. Juan

Comment: Thanks a lot Juan. Could you please share if any sample wlst you have executed for security changes/updates on the proxy service please.

Comment: Thanks Juan. Did you tried this scenario,  modifying the wls/OWSM policies using the script on sbconsole.

Answer (score 0):

You don't really need to edit the wlst.sh present under oracle_common/common/bin

instead execute wlst.sh  located at `$yourMW_home//Oracle_Home/osb/tools/configjar/wlst.sh`

```
===========
#!/bin/sh

WLST_PROPERTIES="$JAVA_OPTS"
export WLST_PROPERTIES

WLST_EXT_CLASSPATH=$CLASSPATH
export WLST_EXT_CLASSPATH

"$MW_HOME/oracle_common/common/bin/wlst.sh" $*
wlst.sh (END)
======================
```